# How to parse database data from an asp site?

Tags: asp-classic, sybase-asa

I am working on a legacy web site run on asp. I need to migrate the data, like user accounts and posts, to php or ruby based web site. I got a data file with file extension of .asa. I don't know how to migrate the data into MySQL. Anyone can help?

Comment: We need more details.. what is inside that `.asa` file you mentioned? Where is it located?

Comment: If it turns out that it's a Sybase db you have there, just add the according tag to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in a classic ASP site, an ASA file is just a configuration file. 
Are you really sure the data is stored inside that file?

For me to help you I need you to:

- Confirm that the data is stored inside the ASA file
- Determine how the data is structured (semicolon separated, etc etc)

Comment: Not really a configuration file - global.asa is where code for application-wide event handlers (Application_Start or Request_End) is kept.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I somehow confused it with web.config (which isnt classic ASP).

Comment: Thanks. I logged in the backend, and it tells me the database file is mydata.asa. When i open this file(around 19MB), it is wrongly encoded.

Comment: @Frankel After a little poking around on the web I would guess you're dealing with a [Sybase "Adaptive Server Anywhere" database](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-sas/awg0800e/dbdaen8).